# On an interpretation of metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics

Is it in the literature that metaphysics is merely a chosen groundwork for conceptual truth? For instance, words like "meaning", "morality", etc. all tacitly presuppose a metaphysical edifice erected within the mind?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that metaphysics is of paramount importance and is the foundation of philosophy for without it - without a coherent worldview - we would be hopelessly lost and helpless to deal with reality.  We have to have this groundwork and the axioms that accompany it. Reality exists and is absolute. That is, I don't accept the premise that reality is all just an edifice or rather, that reality is all in the mind. There is an objective, physical reality that exists outside ourselves and we better learn how to deal with that reality (or suffer the consequences).  Metaphysics provides that foundation.

Comment: How does this differ from what is provided by physics?

Comment: Physics is limited to empirical data while metaphysics goes beyond the observable universe to obtain knowledge.  Both are necessary to understand our "reality".

Comment: I think your answered could be improved if you added something about how it differs from physics or if you made your answer a bit more specific. As I read your answer as it stands, I can't see how it differs from what we would get from physics (or other physical/natural sciences).

Comment: Possibly so. However, the question (at least as I understand it) deals with 'conceptual' truth, not 'empirical' truth. And there is the difference from the physical sciences.